# How do I fix the 'BlobService' is not defined' error

Tags: python, azure

I've installed the azure SDK for Python (pip install azure).
I've copied the Python code on the MS Azure Machine Learning Batch patch for the ML web-service into an Anaconda Notebook.
I've replaced all the place holders in the script with actual values as noted in the scripts comments.
When I run the script I get the error: "*NameError: global name 'BlobService' is not defined*" at the script line "*blob_service = BlobService(account_name=storage_account_name, account_key=storage_account_key)*".
Since the "*from azure.storage import **" line at the beginning of the script does not generate an error I'm unclear as to what the problem is and don't know how to fix it.  Can anyone point me to what I should correct?

Answer (score 2):

To work fine,

In CentOS and Windows I write:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
```

But in MacOS X I write:

```
from azure.storage import BlobService
```

**Then I write this:**

```
from sys import platform as _platform
if _platform == "linux" or _platform == "linux2":   # linux
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
elif _platform == "darwin": # OS X
    from azure.storage import BlobService
elif _platform == "win32":  # Windows...
    from azure.storage.blob import BlobService
```

**UPDATE 18/02/2016:**

Today I did an update today with the command

> pip freeze --local | grep -v '^-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs -n1 pip
>   install -U

, and then, azure crashed. THEN, I read in 'https://pypi.python.org/pypi/azure/1.0.3' this:

> Upgrading from azure<1.0 is not supported. You must uninstall the old
>   version first.

```
pip uninstall azure -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt-compute -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt-network -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt-resource -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt-storage -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt-common -y
pip uninstall azure-mgmt-nspkg -y
pip uninstall azure-servicebus -y
pip uninstall azure-storage -y
pip uninstall azure-common -y
pip uninstall azure-nspkg -y
pip install azure
```

And now works fine

Answer (score 1):

James, I figured it out.  I just changed from azure.storage import * to azure.storage.blob import * and it seems to be working.

Comment: Hi, I recommend to review the doc of Azure SDK for Python http://azure-storage.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a long time since I did any Python, but BlobStorage is in the `azure.storage.blob` namespace I believe.

So I don't think your `from azure.storage import *` is pulling it in.

If you've got a code sample in a book which shows otherwise it may just be out of date.

Comment: James, I've just started to learn the rudiments of Python, so I'm not sure what to do, given your comment.  I come from a SQL background so namespaces are rather foreign to me.  Can you be more specific as to the action I should take?

Answer (score 0):

BlobService is function you are trying to call, but it is not defined anywhere. It should be defined when you call `from azure.storage import *`. It is probably not being called, due to a difference in package versions.

Calling `from azure.storage.blob import *` should work, as it is now invoked correctly.